# Beautifulsoup: parsing html – get part of href

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I'm trying to parse

```
<td height="16" class="listtable_1"><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198134729239" target="_blank">76561198134729239</a></td>
```

for the 76561198134729239. and I can't figure out how to do it. what I tried:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://ppm.rep.tf/index.php?p=banlist&page=154")
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
element = soup.find("td", 
{
    "class":"listtable_1",
    "target":"_blank"
})
print(element.text)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are many such entries in that HTML. To get all of them you could use the following:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("http://ppm.rep.tf/index.php?p=banlist&page=154")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for td in soup.findAll("td", class_="listtable_1"):
    for a in td.findAll("a", href=True, target="_blank"):
        print(a.text)
```

This would then return:

```
76561198143466239
76561198094114508
76561198053422590
76561198066478249
76561198107353289
76561198043513442
76561198128253254
76561198134729239
76561198003749039
76561198091968935
76561198071376804
76561198068375438
76561198039625269
76561198135115106
76561198096243060
76561198067255227
76561198036439360
76561198026089333
76561198126749681
76561198008927797
76561198091421170
76561198122328638
76561198104586244
76561198056032796
76561198059683068
76561197995961306
76561198102013044
```

Answer (score 3):

`"target":"_blank"` is a class of anchor tag `a` within the `td` tag. It's not a class of `td` tag.

You can get it like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html="""
<td height="16" class="listtable_1">
    <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198134729239" target="_blank">
        76561198134729239
    </a>
</td>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

print(soup.find('td', {'class': "listtable_1"}).find('a', {"target":"_blank"}).text)
```

Output:

```
76561198134729239
```

Answer (score 2):

`"class":"listtable_1"` belong to `td` tag and `target="_blank"` belong to `a` tag, you should not use them together.

you should use `Steam Community` as an anchor to find the numbers after it.
[image]

OR use URL, The URL contain the info you need and it's easy to find, you can find the URL and split it by `/`:

```
for a in soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile(r'steamcommunity')):
    num = a['href'].split('/')[-1]
    print(num)
```

Code:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
r = requests.get("http://ppm.rep.tf/index.php?p=banlist&page=154")
content = r.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
for td in soup.find_all('td', string="Steam Community"):
    num = td.find_next_sibling('td').text
    print(num)
```

out:

```
76561198143466239
76561198094114508
76561198053422590
76561198066478249
76561198107353289
76561198043513442
76561198128253254
76561198134729239
76561198003749039
76561198091968935
76561198071376804
76561198068375438
76561198039625269
76561198135115106
76561198096243060
76561198067255227
76561198036439360
76561198026089333
76561198126749681
76561198008927797
76561198091421170
76561198122328638
76561198104586244
76561198056032796
76561198059683068
76561197995961306
76561198102013044
```

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned you are trying to check attributes of different elements in a single `find()`. Instead, you can chain `find()` calls as MYGz suggested, or use a single [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select_one("td.listtable_1 a[target=_blank]").get_text()
```

If, you need to locate multiple elements this way, use `select()`:

```
for elm in soup.select("td.listtable_1 a[target=_blank]"):
    print(elm.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

You could chain together two finds in [gazpacho](https://github.com/maxhumber/gazpacho) to solve this problem:

```py
from gazpacho import Soup

html = """<td height="16" class="listtable_1"><a href="http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561198134729239" target="_blank">76561198134729239</a></td>"""
soup = Soup(html)
soup.find("td", {"class": "listtable_1"}).find("a", {"target": "_blank"}).text
```

This outputs:

> '76561198134729239'